# Perform segue from delegate method

Tags: objective-c, delegates, self

I have a segmented control which when clicked the user will be forced to enter a password.

After a successful check the modal screen should dismiss and in the controller with the segmented control a method is called and a segue should be performed to another controller.

The segue itself works but not after the login check. I think this is a problem with the "self"...

Code of delegate class:

```
@protocol LoginUserControllerDelegate
    - (void)proceedAfterLogin:(BOOL)proceedToNextController;
@end

@interface LoginUserController : UIViewController {
    IBOutlet UITextField *loginPWD;
    id<LoginUserControllerDelegate> _delegate;

}

@property (nonatomic, retain) UITextField *loginPWD;
@property (nonatomic, assign) id<LoginUserControllerDelegate> delegate;

- (void)checkLogindata; // checks for correct password
@end

@implementation LoginUserController

@synthesize loginPWD;
@synthesize delegate = _delegate;

- (void)checkLogindata {
    ...
    if ([tempDBPWD isEqualToString:tempLoginPWD]) {
         if (_delegate != nil) {
               [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
               [_delegate proceedAfterLogin:YES];
           }

    }
    ...
}

@end
```

---

The segmented controller with the method:

```
@interface StartViewController : UIViewController <LoginUserControllerDelegate> {
    UISegmentedControl *segmentedControl;
    LoginUserController *_loginUserController;
}

@property (nonatomic,retain) IBOutlet UISegmentedControl *segmentedControl;
@property (nonatomic, retain) LoginUserController *loginUserController;

- (IBAction)segmentedControlIndexChanged:(id)sender;
@end


@implementation StartViewController

@synthesize segmentedControl;
@synthesize loginUserController = _loginUserController;


- (IBAction)segmentedControlIndexChanged:(id)sender
{
    if (self.segmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex == 0) {
       // get delegate
        AppDelegate *appDelegate = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
        UIStoryboard *storyboard = appDelegate.window.rootViewController.storyboard;
        LoginUserController *loginUserControllerView = [storyboard    instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"LoginUserViewID"];    
        loginUserControllerView.delegate = self;
        // now show screen
        [self presentModalViewController:loginUserControllerView animated:YES];

    } else {

    }

}

- (void)proceedAfterLogin:(BOOL)proceedToNextController
{
    if (proceedToNextController) {
        // yes, correct login now perform the segue to the controller
        [[self segmentedControl] setSelectedSegmentIndex:UISegmentedControlNoSegment];
        [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"NextControllerSegueID" sender:self];

    }

}

@end
```

I think the `[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"NextControllerSegueID" sender:self];` is the problem, because self is not correct. Is this where the error arises and how can I achieved my desired behaviour?

Answer (score 1):

You're close, but you need to return to the delegate, and then call dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES. A modal controller can't dismiss itself, so you need to do your login, call back to the delegate, and have the delegate dismiss the modal controller.